# simple_html_dom Ошибка: Allowed memory size

Tags: php, парсер, memory, simple-html-dom

Почему этот код выдает ошибку "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 81793024 bytes)"?

```
public function getPageFromCurl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if($info['http_code'] == 200)
    {
        include 'simple_html_dom.php';
        return str_get_html($response);
    }
}

public function getFilePageInfoTorrent($url)
{
    if(!$article = $this->getPageFromCurl($url))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $serach = $article->find('.row1 a', 0);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($serach);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: 1) какой размер загружаемого документа 2) когда падает, при построении или поиске 3) зачем все это через курл?

Comment: потому что он жрёт больше памяти, чем ему разрешено. Неужели трудно было найти такую ошибку в поисковике? Там полно ответов, где и какой параметр в php.ini нужно поменять, чтобы увеличить память

Comment: 1. страничка весит от силы 1мб, а требует почти 100. Здесь явно что-то не так. 
2. Падает после вызова метода find. 
3. Через курл чтобы иметь возможность авторизоваться

Comment: ini_set("memory_limit","999999M"); не хватает!

Comment: 1 мбайт html кода? это не мало вообще-то.

Comment: @boomuo, если вам одну ссылку надо найти, то пишите свой парсер на регулярке.

Comment: 1мб - это я к примеру, по факту конечно меньше.

Comment: @Visman, найти нужно много чего, это я код просто упростил для наглядности.

Comment: @boomuo, https://github.com/Imangazaliev/DiDOM/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-(1.6.3)

Comment: @ArchDemon да вы прям гений решения проблем. Куда вы там к примеру память увеличите на хостинге где в тарифе 128 метров? Увеличить память это не решение,  а забить на проблему называется.

Comment: @boomuo вы бы поставили `256M`, а не `999999`, а чтобы снять ограничение надо `-1` указать

Comment: @teran, увеличение памяти не решает проблему. Я просто не понимаю куда и зачем требуется 333451264 bytes?

Comment: @boomuo, вы попробовали парсер, на который я дал вам ссылку?

Comment: @Visman, еще нет, но обязательно попробую. Спасибо!